# Creating a custom exception and throwing it from server

Tags: java, maven, client-server

If you create a custom runtime exception and throws it from the server application and you have a Swing client that catch it, where should you save the exception class so that both the EJB jar and Swing application have the exception in its classpath? Do you create it in the domain project (it is a Maven) which both includes in their classpath or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually have three jars within my projects.

- Client
- Api
- Server

Both Client and Server projects depends on the Api.
My Api jar will contain all service interfaces and shared data objects.

Based on your question, I would have this exception within the Api jar.

Comment: Indeed. Such custom exception would be part of public interface, and thus the public API.

Comment: true, its better to keep it in a seprate project and share the jar to the client and with the server.